# WinSCP Script to Loop through Files

Tags: powershell, winscp

I am using the following slightly modified script (from https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_local_move_after_successful_upload) to upload files to an SFTP site on AWS...and in a PRD env I will have to have this run through approx 0.5M small files...

```
param (
    $localPath = "C:\FTP\*.DAT",
    $remotePath = "/",
    $backupPath = "C:\FTP\Complete\"
    )

try
{
    # Load WinSCP .NET assembly
    #Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"
    $ScriptPath = $(Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)
    [Reflection.Assembly]::UnsafeLoadFrom( $(Join-Path $ScriptPath "WinSCPnet.dll") ) | Out-Null
    
    # Setup session options
    $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    HostName = "somewhere.com"
    UserName = "user"
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 XXXXXXXI"
    SshPrivateKeyPath = "C:\blahblah.ppk"
    }
 
    $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
    $transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
    # Look to ignore any file property change errors
    $transferOptions.FilePermissions = $Null # This is default
    $transferOptions.PreserveTimestamp = $False
 
    try
    {
        # Connect
        $session.Open($sessionOptions)
        
        # Upload files, collect results
        $transferResult = $session.PutFiles($localPath, $remotePath)
 
        # Iterate over every transfer
        foreach ($transfer in $transferResult.Transfers)
        {
            # Success or error?
            if ($Null -eq $transfer.Error)
            {
                Write-Host "Upload of $($transfer.FileName) succeeded, moving to backup"
                # Upload succeeded, move source file to backup
                Move-Item $transfer.FileName $backupPath
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host "Upload of $($transfer.FileName) failed: $($transfer.Error.Message)"
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        # Disconnect, clean up
        $session.Dispose()
    }
 
    exit 0
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    exit 1
}
```

The scripts works great, but unfortunately only loads *one* file before disconnecting. The script fails if there is an error loading any of the files, so it *is* working as expected.
But the error I am getting, is
"**Upload of file 'somefile.DAT' was successful, but error occurred while setting the permissions and/or timestamp.**

If the problem persists, turn off setting permissions or preserving timestamp. Alternatively you can turn on 'Ignore permission errors' option.
The server does not support the operation.
Error code: 8
Error message from server (US-ASCII): SETSTAT unsupported"

I think I have the following settings possibly configured incorrectly, but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here....thoughts?

```
    $transferOptions.FilePermissions = $Null # This is default
    $transferOptions.PreserveTimestamp = $False
```

Answer (score 0):

I've actually managed to get this to work by modifying the session and transfer options..

```
 $session.Open($sessionOptions)
    $transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
    # Look to ignore any file property change errors
    $transferOptions.PreserveTimeStamp = $false
    $transferOptions.FilePermissions = $Null
    $transferOptions.AddRawSettings("IgnorePermErrors",  "1")
    
    # Upload files, collect results
    $transferResult = $session.PutFiles($localPath, $remotePath, $False, $transferOptions)
```

Comment: The actual fix is that you pass the `$transferOptions` to the `session.PutFiles`. In your original code you didn't use the constructed `$transferOptions` at all. So it's not correct so say that you *"get this to work by modifying the session and transfer options"*.